# sizing issue of gridview in nested scrollview

Tags: nestedscrollview

[you can see gridview in the image which is not wrapping whole nestedscrollview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNl0D.png) Guys please help me I am stucked in this code, I need a collapsing toolbar layout and I succeed too but the gridview inside the nested scrollview is not wrapping total space of nestedscrollview, I tried many ways but failed.

This is the xml which is helping me to collapse toolbar and where I am getting gridview issues,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.patelsanket.myalbum.activities.AlbumImageDisplayActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/headerImage1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/shows_header_image"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/cod" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<GridView

        android:id="@+id/album_image_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="550dip"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0.5dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip" />

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:backgroundTint="#009688"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end|right" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **RecyclerView** with **GridLayoutManager**. As Recycler view is compitable with Collasping bartoolbar too...
I hope it helps..

Comment: Yes, this is a proper way. But those who haven't used recyclerview then what i answered will also work well.

Answer (score 2):

After searching a lot I found that using expandable gridview it can be solved. I used the following class and it is working fine.

This is a custom implementation of the native GridView , 
 Here we override the functionality pertaining to GridView's height.
 This implementation does away with a fixed Height GridView , rather 
 the height of the GridView expands depending upon the number of child elements    added into it.

```
public class ExpandableGridView extends GridView{

    boolean expanded = false;
    public boolean isExpanded()
    {
        return expanded;
    }

    public ExpandableGridView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {

        if (isExpanded())
        {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
            // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(   
                    Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);   
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        else
        {      
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
    {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            album_image_grid_view.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        }
or you can use RecyclerView instead of GridView

Comment: thanks to reply but it is not working but days before I found its solution.

Comment: haven't tried the RecyclerView... coz I have implemented gridview so had to find something else. @andy